# ObjectDataProvider in .Net 5 throws System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-5

I am trying to use `ObjectDataProvider` in a `.Net-5` Web App. Therefore I need to use `System.Windows.Data`, which can be used with the `PresentationFramework.dll`. I included the assembly with [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PresentationFramework/) (`<PackageReference Include="PresentationFramework" Version="4.6.0" />`). Already when I build my app I get the following warnings:

```
warning NU1701: Package 'PresentationFramework 4.6.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Then, when I try to make an `ObjectDataProvider` object with `ObjectDataProvider myODP = new ObjectDataProvider();` my App crashes with:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)
      File name: 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
```

I am running my app in a Linux docker container (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal`) on an x64 system if that is of interest.

From my Google searches, I already tried to delete the `bin` folder and to rebuild, without success.
Other answers seem to suggest that `System.BadImageFormatException` indicates that an x86 assembly is referenced, while I am building for x64. I seem not to be able to find any other version of the `PresentationFramework.dll` except the one from NuGet.
Or is `ObjectDataProvider` just [deprecated](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1199)?

My question is: How can I resolve this issue and make `ObjectDataProvider` work in `.Net-5`?
Is it even possible to use `PresentationFramework.dll` in `.Net-5`?
By the way, I also tried to make it work in `.Net-3.1`, resulting in the same issue.

Comment: *I seem not to be able to find any other version* - see, this is one of the problems with nuget; people can take DLLs that are part of some official distribution SDK or the framework etc and package them up individually, so they can hack together something to get an old project working in some form.. but then other people find them, install them and assume it'll work out for them. This clearly isn't an official package from Microsoft, intended to be used in the way you're using. What it's doing is *causing* an incompatible reference assembly to end up in your bin folder..

Comment: So all those "clear your bin folder" advices won't work out because the build process will put it back, and it begins again. I dare say if you need to use this dll you'll have to make this part of your app using .net fw (where it should already be available without an unofficial nuget) and adapt or provide whatever it does as a service to the rest of your app - you can't assume that everything you find on nuget is compatible with every project type you can create in vs

Comment: Thank @CaiusJard . I am not sure yet, but it seems I cannot use the .net fw in my linux docker. But, I could now also become one of those guys __hacking something together to get my project working and upload it to nuget__ if I have access to the dll I need, which I guess I would have to check in .net fw.

Comment: Also when I try to include the assembly with `<Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />` I get the following error: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.200\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "PresentationFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. `

Comment: [`ObjectDataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider?view=net-5.0) is used in WPF and XAML mostly, which are windows specific. Why do you need it in web app and why do you think that it'll run on linux docker container?

Comment: target your app as **.net5.0-windows** set **<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>** this adds the correct [WPF references](https://apisof.net/catalog/f7163cd6-32bc-a951-c246-1671848362ac?fx=net5.0-windows). But as the name indicates this makes the app only run on Windows as WPF is still Windows only.